# Object is cloned , but static references still exists?

Tags: java, object, clone, static-methods

I was learning about object deep cloning , I have an employee class with a getInstance method which returns a singleton and I am cloning the returned object.Below is the class and test class.

```
public class Employee  implements Serializable , Cloneable {

    public static Employee employee;

    private String name;

    private int age;


    private Employee(){


    }


    public Employee(String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {

        return super.clone();

        }


    public static Employee getInstance(){

        if(employee == null ){
            employee = new Employee();
            return employee;
        }


        return employee;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}
```

**Object deep copy test class**

```
public class CopyTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        try {

            Employee original = Employee.getInstance();

            original.setName("John");
            original.setAge(25);

            Employee cloned = (Employee)copy(original);

            System.out.println("Original -->"+Employee.getInstance().getName());

            cloned.getInstance().setName("Mark");

            System.out.println("Cloned -->"+cloned.getInstance().getName());

            System.out.println("Original -->"+Employee.getInstance().getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static Object copy(Object orig) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            // Write the object out to a byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(orig);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            // Make an input stream from the byte array and read
            // a copy of the object back in.
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
            obj = in.readObject();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Original -->John
Cloned -->Mark
Original -->Mark
```

### Problem

Eventhough I clone the original object to create a copy of it ,

```
Employee cloned = (Employee)copy(original);
```

And I modify the cloned object's property by calling

```
cloned.getInstance().setName("Mark");
```

It is reflecting to the original object as you can see from the console output. **I assume this is because of the static call ? , and how do I overcome this ?** Am I violating the principle that I need a single instance of the object by getInstance method and then I decided to make a copy of the object later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what the [JAVA Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) tutorial page says:

> Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called
>   static fields or class variables. They are associated with the class,
>   rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a
>   class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory. Any object
>   can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also
>   be manipulated without creating an instance of the class.

The cloned object `cloned` is just another object of the class. It is not changing another object to which it doesn't have a reference. your call `cloned.getInstance()` is returning the static object `employee` to which all the object can access, because static object associate with `Class`, not to any specific object. So you call to `cloned.getInstance().setName("Mark");` is just equivalent to `Employee.employee.setName("Mark");`

Comment: "Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory." made it clear for me. accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the name on `Employee` instance of the `static` field `employee`

```
cloned.getInstance().setName("Mark");
      ^ static method call that returns the employee reference
```

and printing it too

```
System.out.println("Cloned -->"+cloned.getInstance().getName());
                                      ^ static method call
```

You might want to actually change the `cloned` instance

```
cloned.setName("Mark");
System.out.println("Cloned -->"+cloned.getName());
```

Comment: I did it on purpose , so that means the getInstance () will always refer to the original object , even if its cloned ?

Comment: @TitoCheriachan The `getInstance()` method is `static`. It has no relation to the instance. You just happened to call it on an object instead of on the type. `cloned.getInstance()` is equivalent to `Employee.getInstance()` in this case.

Comment: So this means a cloned object can mischievously modify the original object if there is a static reference to it. So as a rule of thumb , If I want the object to be cloned , I should not expose a static method of its class ?

Comment: @TitoCheriachan This has nothing to do with a cloned object. It has to do with you calling the `set` and `get` methods on the object referenced by the `static` field instead of your `cloned` reference.

Answer (score 1):

A static field roughly means that it will be shared by every object. Regardless how many objects you have created/cloned, your getInstance() call will return the same Employee.

Therefor, as soon as you set its name as Mark, you will always get Mark in the console.

For example:

```
Employee me = new Employee();
Employee.getInstance().setName("Mark");
System.out.println("me employee name? " + me.getInstance().getName());
```

Don´t be surprised if you get "Mark" in the console ;)

For a more detailed information about the difference between instance and class (using the static keyword) members, have a look to this [tutorial section](http://goo.gl/ogvK3q)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to serialize the object, then deserialize it. In java, deserialization is guaranteed to create a new object. (has to do with how Classloader's work).

When you serialize the object, it does a Deep Copy of the object and all it's dependencies, etc. Serialization can be used in a number of ways, but one way is to convert objects down to bytes so it can be sent over the wire (network), or stored on disk for persistence. You can use the behavior to do an in-memory serialization/deserialization and create a new object every time with exactly the same contents (values) but a different reference than the original.

here's a method I have working in production in some app:

```
/**
 * Clones an object creating a brand new
 * object by value of input object. Accomplishes this
 * by serializing the object, then deservializing it.
 * 
 * @param obj Input Object to clone
 * @return a new List<Product> type cloned from original.
 * @throws IOException If IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException If ClassNotFoundException
 */
private static List<Product> cloneProdList(Object obj) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    obj_out.writeObject(obj);

    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream bis = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    java.io.ObjectInputStream obj_in = new java.io.ObjectInputStream(bis);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Product> newObj = (List<Product>)obj_in.readObject();

    bos.close();
    bis.close();
    obj_out.close();
    obj_in.close();

    return newObj;
}
```

Comment: @TitoCheriachan the `clone()` method rarely works. You will need to do the serialization yourself, such as I have provided in the example above.

Comment: I not using clone , I am using a custom method copy(..) , just like your sample code.


Employee cloned = (Employee)copy(original);

Comment: @TitoCheriachan oh you know what, I forgot to scroll down in your example! now I see where you handle the serialization. ;-P

Comment: @TitoCheriachan in that case, i'm going with, if you "clone" a static object, then by definition of static, it's going to be the same reference. Static can only have 1 living in the JVM at the same time.

Comment: @SnakeDoc OP is cloning an object, not a reference. The object will be completely different. The `static` field reference will not change however.